# Draw animations dynamically (interactively) on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, quartz-core

I want to draw an animation over MKMapView. I want it to be something like a compass arrow, that follows (rotates) user's taps / swipes .

So the arrow goes from the center of the screen and is of a fixed length. I don't need the line to be coordinate-specific, but I need to keep the map interactions intact (i.e. still being able to pinch-zoom on the map).

I tried to do that via MKPolyline (creating and then destroying a line), but that does not work (and from the way I had to do that I feel like it won't work). I wonder what would be the best way to handle that? Quartz?

I would accept just an explanation (which kind of view overlay over what, which classes to use), no code is necessary (but if you have a working example that's so much better ))

Answer (score 0):

I draw views like a map ruler not as subview from MkMapView. I put kMapView and my ruler view into a container view. This works for views which positions are fixed on screen, like on center of screen, and are not related to a geographical position.